# can I wrap up my existing code into function?

Tags: r, function

how can i code R function, which wraps up my existing code & executes when function used? my code is about reading csv files & validating it & counting total score...this below is code->

I want to wrap this above code in a function with inputfilename and outputfilename as parameter when i give inputfilename then above code should run & give output file name total so how do i create a function of this code ?

Comment: If you need a function, instead of `subset` use `[`

Comment: If you have multiple files, you can change the code slightly by reading all the files at once in a list and cleaning it all together instead of reading file one by one and doing the same operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this along the skeleton:

```
compute_total <- function(input_file_name) {
  qdat2 <- read.table(input_file_name, header = TRUE, sep = ",")

  # your code goes here

  return(total)
}
```

Call this like

```
total <- compute_total("name_of_first_input_file")
write.table(total, "name_of_first_output_file")
```

Comment: I'm stuck now. Would need to see your function definition and call.

Comment: Thanks. So you are reading `check_data` from a second csv file? Then you need to pass the name of this file as second parameter to the function.

Comment: Reading the same file from disk isn't very efficient. I'm sorry, we can't do a "remote debugging session" on SO. Please, try to find out what's going on with adding some `print` statements in the function body.